# How do I specify tab(\t) as a separator for text in a Dataflow Template?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

There are some Dataflow templates that support `Column delimiter of the data files` as an optional parameter (for instance, the template loading Text Files into Spanner), but I am unable to pass tabulator (i.e. `\t`) as a column delimiter. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the Dataflow UI that made it impossible to pass escaped characters to a Dataflow template.

Gladly, this is no longer the case. To specify tab as a delimiter, you can simply pass `\\t`, and the template will work as expected.

For passing any other parameter, note that you can escape any character. (e.g. `\\n`, `\\t`, etc).